# Closedness of $R(\lambda -T)$ when $T$ closed symmetric operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a closed symmetric operator defined on a Hilbert space.

I want to proof that the Rang $R(\lambda - T)$ is closed if and only if $Im(\lambda)\neq 0$.

I used the sequences technic to proof that if $Im(\lambda)\neq 0$ then the equality hold, but I couldn't see why it is not true if $Im(\lambda)= 0$  !!!

I proceed like the following

if $T$ is closed operator  so $(\lambda - T)$ too, then $R(\lambda - T)$ is close.

Could someone give me a counter-example or any clarification, please?

Comment: It's not necessarily true for a selfadjoint operator $T$, and such a $T$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you sir, yes we can show that that rang is closed even if $Im(\lambda)=0$ for exemple when $T$ is self-adjoint and $\lambda = 0 $ :)

Comment: Let $\lambda_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Define $Tf=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n \langle f,e_n\rangle e_n$, where $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$. Then $(T-\lambda I)$ does not have a closed range for any real $\lambda$ that is a cluster point of $\{ \lambda_n \}$.

Comment: If $T=T^*$ and $T-\lambda I$ has trivial null space for some real $\lambda$, then $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(T-\lambda)$ shows that $T-\lambda I$ has dense range. If that range is also closed, then $T-\lambda I$ will be invertible, which means that $\lambda\in\rho(T)$.

Comment: Thank you, i think i am not in that advanced level as your explication!, can you please tell me where is the problem if $\lambda \in \rho(T)$ ?

Comment: A selfadjoint operator $T$ can have a dense range and trivial null space. In that case, the range will not be closed. For example, $Tf=xf(x)$ on $L^2[-1,1]$. The operator $T$ has no null space, and a dense (but not closed) range. The same is true of $T-\lambda I$ for all $\lambda \in [1,1]$.

Comment: thank you a lot ; it is so clear now :)

Comment: You're welcome. The thing to keep in mind about selfadjoint operators is there are two kinds of spectrum: eigenvalues and approximate eigenvalues. ($\lambda$ in the spectrum can be both.) If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue only, then the range of $T-\lambda I$ is closed; otherwise the range is never closed.

Comment: @D.abdelhakim: I suggest you write an answer to your own question. It will help you, and other who might read your question in the future.

Comment: Thank you @MartinArgerami i will try